# WindowsError The system cannot find the file specified in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

Getting above error when i tried to use SparkContext, getting the error 
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified in pyspark
Can you please help me on this issue .

Comment: can you add more details, if you re defining any SparkConf etc ?